# Trigger multiple Jenkins builds with GitHub Pull Request Builder

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

Currently, I have a Jenkins job setup so that when a pull request is opened for my repository, a Jenkins job is automatically created via the [GitHub Pull Request Builder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin).

I would like to be able to trigger multiple Jenkins jobs when a PR is opened in my GitHub repository and have the GitHub Pull Request Builder report the status back to the PR. Is this achievable via the GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin or are there other plugins available for this? My research has me coming up empty-handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this, and realized I did not provide enough context in my initial question. Specifically, I am configuring my Jenkins job as part of a GitHub Organization. A single GitHub Organization only supports one Jenkinsfile; one cannot configure the same organization to use two separate Jenkinsfile. So, I imported the same GitHub Organization in my Jenkins instance and configured it to use the other Jenkinsfile. This results in multiple jobs appearing above as you have it configured.

Comment: How did you set Github Pull Request Builder Plugin Trigger in Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a Jenkins job for each PR Check, like so:
[image]

Each one of those jenkins jobs is using the Git Hub Pull Request Builder.
Just make sure to configure it with a unique name, and you should be good to go:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying ! Is there a separate Jenkins instance for each of those jobs? Using your example - i.e., I have one Jenkins instance for the cron-checker, another for the conformity-checker, or would I provide "cron-checker conformity-checker" all in the "Commit Status Context"?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I have a single jenkins master.  Each one of those PR checks is a separate job that runs on the jenkins master.  So when someone makes a commit to the PR, github sends a single signal to the jenkins master and then the jenkins master will trigger all those jobs.  Hope this helps!

Comment: The key thing I don't understand though, is how the Jenkins master triggers those multiple jobs. How do I get to the "Trigger Setup" for the job as you have it? My GitHub Pull Request Builder configuration for Jenkins does not have that. I appreciate your help and patience with this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you get multiple jobs to run on a single repository? I'm having trouble with this. Can you post an example Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @Christian I am not using a Jenkinsfile. I'm using a freestyle job  :(  In my freestyle job, under the checkbox "GitHub Pull Request Builder", there is a Trigger Setup button, where I configure it.