# Adding a button to a Github Push Request that will trigger a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

There are plenty of articles that explain how to trigger a Jenkins job when code it pushed to Github, but I'm interested in a different use case.

When a pull request is created in Github I would like a number of buttons to be added to the pull request. Clicking one of these buttons would trigger a specific Jenkins job for the associated pull request to be run.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you would need to make a userscript for that

Comment: That's not really maintainable, I'm looking for a native solution. For instance Github is capable of displaying the status of Jenkins jobs, I was hoping for something similar in this case. There's a illustration here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561057/11908063

Comment: I think it could be possible to embed an image with link in markdown (like a badge) that would call a backend that would trigger the Jenkins job via API.

Comment: I think you refer to Github checks https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/runs/ but you would like the checks to be run manually instead of automatically, is that right ?

Comment: I've found this post : https://github.community/t/trigger-check-run-manually/16908 for tracking the issue